# I/O File Exception: ArrayList Values w/o including the first two elements (JAVA)

Tags: java, arraylist, average, ioexception, try-with-resources

I need to know how to form an equation for the sum without using the first two values of my ArrayList from I/O File Exception.
My sum should not include the first two elements which are the weight, 0.5 and the lowest number, 3. All the values are: 0.5, 3, 10, 70, 90, 80, 20. These numbers come from the input file, "data.txt". Also, I need to make try-with-resources Statement. I'm new to this and just learned but I wanted to know how I can apply it on my own program.

```
public class CalcWeightedAvgDropLowest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

       ArrayList<Double> inputValues = getData();
       double weightedAvg = calcWeightedAvg(inputValues);
       printResults(inputValues, weightedAvg);

}

public static ArrayList<Double> getData() throws FileNotFoundException {       

        // Prompts for the input file names                     

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
        ArrayList<Double> inputValues = new ArrayList<Double>(); 

        while (in.hasNextDouble())
            {
                inputValues.add(in.nextDouble());                    
            }         

        in.close();


        return inputValues;
}

public static double calcWeightedAvg(ArrayList<Double> inputValues) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // calc weighted av          
     double sum = 0;
     double average = 0;                
     int i = 0;
     double weightavg = 0;


            // Calcuates the average of the array list with the lowest numbers dropped
            // calculated average is 42.5
            for (i = 0; i < inputValues.size(); i++) 
            {                    
                if (inputValues.get(i) > inputValues.get(1)) 
                { 
                   // **I just need an equation for the sum here w/o the first two values.**
                }
            }
            average = sum /inputValues.size();

            weightavg = average * inputValues.get(0);


            return weightavg;
}

public static void printResults(ArrayList<Double> inputValues, double weightedAvg) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Output File: ");
        String outputFileName = scnr.next();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
            out.print("The weighted average of the numbers is " + weightedAvg + ", when using the data " + inputValues + ", where " +inputValues.get(0)+ " is the weight used, and the average is computed after dropping the lowest " +inputValues.get(1)+ " values.");
            out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "first two", are these elements 0 and 1, or are they the two smallest elements?

Comment: @AndyTurner The first two elements, 0 and 1.

Comment: You can just start at the position 2 instead of 0

Comment: @LuizAgner did you mean like this
 `for (i = 2; i < inputValues.size(); i++)`

Comment: @OliveBassey Exactly. It will then start at the third position (index 2) of your `inputValues` array, ignoring the first two `Double` numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a view of the list elements from 2 to the end using:

```
List<Double> view = inputValues.subList(2, inputValues.size());
```

(assuming you've got at least 2 elements in the list).

Then change the parameter of `calcWeightedAverage` to `List<Double>`, and pass `view` instead:

```
calcWeightedAvg(view);
```

Comment: How will this work? I need the parameter inputValues for calcWeightAvg for it to find the arraylist elements from getData() method.

Comment: You said you need to skip the first 2 elements. This skips the first two elements.